# Joi how to validate one of two field should not be empty

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I have following validation schema, and sample data.

```
var schema = Joi.alternatives().try(
  Joi.object().keys({
    searchTerm: Joi.string().trim().min(3).label('Search Term').options({ language: { any: { empty: 'should not be empty' } } }),
    location: Joi.string().allow(''),
    searchType: Joi.string().valid('people')
  }),
  Joi.object().keys({
    searchTerm: Joi.string().allow(''),
    location: Joi.string().trim().min(3).label('Location').options({ language: { any: { empty: 'should not be empty' } } }),
    searchType: Joi.string().valid('people')
  })
);
```

Sample data is:

```
{searchTerm: "", searchType: "people", location: ""}
```

Should not pass and show a message `Please enter either search term or location. Make sure it contains 3 characters at least`

```
{searchTerm: "as", searchType: "people", location: ""}
```

Should not pass and show a message `Search term must contain 3 characters at least`

```
{searchTerm: "test", searchType: "people", location: ""}  // Should pass
```

My validation schema shows both message in failure situations

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your joi schema to this

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  searchTerm: Joi.string().trim().min(3),
  location: Joi.string().allow(''),
  searchType: Joi.string().valid('people'),
}).or('searchTerm', 'location').error(new Error('Please enter either search term or location. Make sure it contains 3 characters at least'));
```

However this will not meet your second condition(`Search term must contain 3 characters at least`) as there can be only one error message.